# Adding an icons to backend submenu items

Tags: component, joomla-3.4, submenu, icon

I've started developing my first ever component and an using Joomla's `JSubMenuHelper` class to add a sub-menu to define the different views, like so:

```
public static function addSubmenu($submenu) 
{
    JSubMenuHelper::addEntry(
        JText::_('COM_SHOUTBOX_SUBMENU_SHOUTS'),
        'index.php?option=com_shoutbox',
        $submenu == 'shouts'
    );
}
```

This works perfectly fine and output the following:

[image]

However, I would like to add an icon before the string like Kunena have done. (See below image)

[image]

Kunena have manually constructed their menu which I *could* do too, however I would prefer to stick to using Joomla's `addEntry` method.

So my question is, how can I add an icon to each menu item?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the first parameter of addEntry() for that, for example:

```
public static function addSubmenu($submenu) 
{
    JSubMenuHelper::addEntry(
        '<i class="icon-home"></i>' . JText::_('COM_SHOUTBOX_SUBMENU_SHOUTS'),
        'index.php?option=com_shoutbox',
        $submenu == 'shouts'
    );
}
```

This would add the home icon to your menu label.
You can see a list of icons that come with the An overview of all icons shipped with the Isis template can be found here: http://kyleledbetter.com/jui/icons/

addEntry documentation: https://api.joomla.org/cms-3/classes/JHtmlSidebar.html#method_addEntry

Comment: Not sure why I didn't think if this initially :/ Thanks fruppel, much appreciated :)